# wget not getting all files

Tags: wget

I have issues using wget,

basically I use it like:

```
wget -m ftp://username:password@hostname.com:/path/to/dirs
```

After everything's complete (it says xxx files in xx MB for xx seconds), however, when I inspect the files, I notice it actually didn't completely download everything, am I missing something?

Comment: By "completely download," are you saying (a) It only downloaded some of the files completely, or (b) it download all of the files, but some of them have only partial content?

Comment: it's (a), any idea what's causing it?

Comment: This might be a duplicate of: http://serverfault.com/questions/178607/problems-using-wget-to-transfer-files-from-an-ftp-server/178880#178880

Comment: I have also issues that despite `--mirror --page-requisites` some CSS file is not downloaded. Still investigating why.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your command (except a missing port, which wget can handle).

How are you verifying your local files are the same as the remote ones? You could try retrieving a problematic file with [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) for comparison. If you are certain they're different then I suspect it's something to do with the FTP server.

Check:

- the FTP server's transfer logs - are the transfers listed as complete?
- in wget's output: is the Length header returned or do you see Length: unspecified
- any errors in wget's output